# Area of a square with double the area of another square

Tags: geometry

There are 2 squares, one with an area of $a^2$ and another with an area of $b^2$, and when this is true: $(a+b)^2=2a^2$ and: $2b^2=c^2$ then: $b+c=a$.

My question is, is this called anything? I know this is pretty vague but I just want to know if this property has a name. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two equations in three unknowns, so should expect a one dimensional space of solutions.  In this case both your equations are homogeneous in scale, so you can scale everything by $a$. Set $a=1, b'=\frac ba, c'=\frac ca$. Then $(1+b')^2=2,\ \  2b'^2=c'^2$ so $b'=\pm (\sqrt 2 -1), c'^2=\pm(3-2\sqrt 2)$ where the signs do not have to correspond.  Now check if $b'+c'=1$ to check the sign constraint.

Comment: $c' = \sqrt{2}-1$, so $c'^2 = 2-2\sqrt{2}+1 = 3-2\sqrt{2}$.